# How to access one php variable in another web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Facing some problem while accessing session variable in another web page

i have tried using jquery to refresh the page which create the session(data.php) also the database connection and sql query works fine, tested them independently.

**test.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="show">   </div>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function () {
                $('#show').load('data.php')  // reloades data.php repetedly
                }, 1000);
        });
        </script>

        <?php   echo $_SESSION["id"];  ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php    
session_start();


$conn = new mysqli("localhost","id6207501_datausername","123456789","id6207501_dataname");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
$result = $conn->query("SELECT status,id FROM logs order by id desc limit 1");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION["id"]=$row['id'];
    $_SESSION["status"]=$row['status'];

     }
}

?>
```

i expect the test.php to print the value of session variable `$_SESSION["id"]`, which it does not.

Comment: why not just include `data.php` on your `test.php`?

Comment: You will have to return value of session as a variable because you are missing up things you want to run php on client side which is not possible because php is server side language so first you have to return values from data.php and set it below in the code in js variable.

Comment: You are loading the page within a template, but the session need a page to reload to reflect the result

Comment: You can use local storage from jquery instead of session to store temporary values

Comment: @Gulshan localStorage has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Why are you calling server side in client side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call AJAX get method and set return your text in `data.php` file.

**test.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>

<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function () {

            $.get("data.php", function(data, status){
                $('#show').html(data);
            });
            }, 1000);
    </script>

 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="show"> <?php   echo $_SESSION["id"];  ?>  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php    
session_start();

// You can uncomment it and test

// $conn = new mysqli("localhost","id6207501_datausername","123456789","id6207501_dataname");
//     if ($conn->connect_error) {
//     die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
//     }
// $result = $conn->query("SELECT status,id FROM logs order by id desc limit 1");
// if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//     echo $_SESSION["id"]=$row['id'];
//     echo $_SESSION["status"]=$row['status'];

//      }
// }

    // Comment when you uncomment DB
    // FOR example purpose 
    $_SESSION["id"]= rand(1,2000);

    echo $_SESSION["id"];

?>
```

Comment: That's really helpfull if you could help me find out which type of variable is 'data' that we fetch using  $.get("data.php", function(data, status))  because i'm getting some type mismatch error. thanks!

Comment: If it's helpful do not forget to accept and up vote my answer, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use localstorage.
Set your variable value in the first page.

```
<script>localstroage.setItem("myItem","value");</script>
```

And get the value in the other page by using getItem

```
<script>var x = localstroage.getItem("myItem");</script>
```

Or cockies

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";</script>
```

And in php page

```
  <?php $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['cookieName'];echo $phpVar ;?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, check if session working on any page or not then

Add this line at the top

```
<?php

ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
session_start();
```

This works with both redirecting from PHP by using `header('Location: ')` and with JavaScript `window.location`.

Comment: ViperTecPro, do you know why this should be necessary? Like the OP, I thought `$_SESSION["id"]="whatever"` (and `session_start();`) was all the server needed to let us access a variable from the $_SESSION array.

Comment: You don't need session.save_path to save session, it saves itself

Comment: But i thought to make session world wide available we need to set it otherwise will just be for browser

Comment: Please someone let me understand what is the problem with my answer ?